# How to redeploy spring boot application on STS built-in server

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, localserver

I have a Spring Boot Gradle application with `apply plugin: 'war'`. I run the application on STS by `right click > Run As > Spring Boot App`. It runs fine. Now I make a change to the code and I want to redeploy (and better automatically). The only way I know now is to stop the server and run again.  Is there any faster solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-boot provide something called `devtools` which is a very neat feature.

Include this starter on your gradle build

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

This will automatically restart whenever files on the classpath changes. So you don't have to manually stop and start server.

you can see more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html).